# Trigger JavaScript event on different target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have a element which adds a child to itself when a `mousedown` or `touchstart` event occurs. This child is `resizable` (jQuery ui widget). I use http://touchpunch.furf.com/ which enables jquery-ui widgets for touch devices.

I want to resize the child when it gets created without lifting the mouse/touch and clicking again. It works for mouse devices but I fail to trigger it when using a touch device.

Check the snippet (works for mouse, fails with touch).

1. `Mousedown` on blue element (red element is created)
2. Keep mouse down and drag to the right (red element gets resized)

I fail making it work for a touch device.
I create the element on `touchstart`, but I am not able to resize it without lifting my finger.

I basically want to achieve the same with touch as with the mouse. Problem is I don't know how the `event`  must look like which I have to trigger on the resize-handle.

I check if it is a touch event and try to change the `event.target` but this does not work.

```
if (event.type === "touchstart") {
  console.log("here I am stuck")
  event.target = handler[0];
  item.trigger(event);    
}
```

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on("mousedown touchstart", ".resizeCreator", function(event){
    if ($(this).find("div").length){
      return;
    }
    
    //Add resizable div
    $(this).append("<div>resize me</div>");
    $(this).find("div").resizable({handles: "e"});    
    simulateHandleEvent($(this).find("div"), event)
  });
  
  $(document).on("click", "button", function(){
    $(".resizeCreator").find("div").remove();
  });
})

var simulateHandleEvent = function(item, event){
  var handler = item.find(".ui-resizable-e").first();
  
  if (event.type === "touchstart") {
    console.log("here I am stuck")
    event.target = handler[0];
    item.trigger(event);    
  }else{
    handler.trigger("mouseover");
    handler.trigger({
    type: "mousedown",
    which: 1,
    pageX: handler.offset().left,
    pageY: handler.offset().top
  });    
  }
}
```

```css
.resizeCreator{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  padding:5px;
  border:1xp solid black;
  background-color:blue;
}

.resizeCreator div{
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="resizeCreator">

</div>

<button>reset</button>
```

Comment: Where is the code? if you can create a pen then sure can create a snippet click `<>`

Comment: its in the question: http://codepen.io/SCHTAILian/pen/RpzrmW/

Comment: didn't know pens aren't liked anymore; edited.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question. However only pen/fiddle is not appreciated.

Comment: Would advise using a CDN and not raw Git: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Comment: Created Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/21scnkLv/ Test with Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/21scnkLv/show/

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue in my fiddle. I can resize the red `div` both via FireFox and Chrome on Mobile and Desktop.

Comment: Improved fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/21scnkLv/4/ & for mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/21scnkLv/4/show/

Comment: yes, i am able to resize, but not with the first mousedown.On touch, i need to click the resize handler after the div is created. While, with a mouse, i keep the mouse button down and resize the div left and right.